# Files not found after moving host

Tags: php, host, file-management

I moved host the other day and copied an exact copy of the structure and files from the old host to the new one. The structure is the same and if I ftp to my new host, I can see them all sitting there the way they were on the old host. Problem is that I now get loads of php-errors saying that certain files don't exist; it can't find the pics on the website anymore, etc., even though I can see them sitting there the entire time. While it has no problem finding some files, other files it just doesn't see anymore, even files in the same directory with one another.

I have never seen this before, can anybody tell me what is going on here?

Comment: relative vs full urls\file paths? file\directory permissions?

Comment: Thanks for your answer!Directory permissions are all set to 755, file perms to 644 (standard) and I tried both the full url and a relative path - same result.

Comment: show us one error, and the code, and the file path

Comment: In fact I tried to set the page that it could not find on perms 777 and the host slapped me with a 403 access forbidden msg.

Comment: its more likely the file path issue, than the directory permissins

Comment: Warning: include_once(regpro.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/<mydomain>/public_html/sub_members/profiletemp.php on line 2

Comment: it gives me this with a relative path as well as with a full url.

Comment: simply the file is not where you code is looking for it.

Comment: I can see it sitting in the folder where it is supposed to look if I ftp to it.

Comment: I 'trust' php over you, there's some difference your just not seeing, cant be much more useful than that with out direct access :-)

Comment: Thanks anyway for your replies, really appreciate your efforts :-)

Comment: @JohnB.Verhoef   Are you sure that /home/<mydomain>/public_html/sub_members/regpro.php exists and in that directory?

Comment: No it is in the php_includes folder, where it is supposed to be - the profiletemp is in the sub_members main folder. However, I found a workaround - I had an identical page which I originally intended for some other purpose sitting in the same folder. The purpose has become void some time ago, so I adjusted a few settings and there it went, it's working again now. So thanks a million guys for your efforts it is really appreciated. Cheers from Ireland :)

Comment: sounds like you just need to add php_includes folder to the path var in php.ini